# why am i getting error as "InputMismatchException" while executing code on hackerRank?

Tags: java, list

I am able to  execute code successfully in Eclipse IDE but i am getting error on HackerRank only. This error is because of scanner.nextInt() but why eclipse is executing this program successfully while hackerrank is throwing exception?

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-list/problem

```
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            List<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int n,x,y,d;
            n=scanner.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                list1.add(scanner.nextInt());
            int q=scanner.nextInt();
            if(q==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Insert");
                x=scanner.nextInt();
                y=scanner.nextInt();
                list1.add(x,y);
                System.out.println(list1);
            }
            if(q==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Insert");
                x=scanner.nextInt();
                y=scanner.nextInt();
                list1.add(x,y);
                System.out.println("Delete");
                d=scanner.nextInt();
                list1.remove(d);
                System.out.println(list1);

            }


            scanner.close();

    HackerRank Error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at Solution.main(Solution.java:27)

    Eclipse executes successfully :

    5
    12
    0
    1
    78
    12
    1
    Insert
    0
    50
    [50, 12, 0, 1, 78, 12]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are executing it on the same input as HackerRank? no extra characters or anything?

Comment: yes, no extra characters. you can also try.

Comment: I think you understood the question wrong? The input on hackerrank clearly contains "Insert" and other string-words, yet you are not *reading* them, you are *printing* them. HackerRank gives you strings as input, which is why your program fails. You're feeding it hackerranks output. Or did I oversee something?

Comment: yup, My bad I understood question wrongly. Thank you for guidance. program got successfully executed.